# Complex MySQL Query, I Am So Close I Can Smell It

Tags: mysql

I've created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f25a6/2) (thanks, [Amadan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240443/amadan)!) with my schema and some test data. The calculated columns aren't working for some reason in SQLFiddle, but they come out fine in my MYSQL Workbench. Assume they work correctly.

I've gotten this far with my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.orderid,i.invoiceid,i.subinvoicenumber,stockingorderid AS oistockingorderid,

IF(stockingorderid > 0, 0, po.purchaseorderid) AS purchaseorderid,subponumber,po.paidvia,dropshipfee,i.taxstate,

COALESCE(
    (SELECT mfrname 
        FROM cs_products.tblstockingorders so 
        WHERE so.stockingorderid=oistockingorderid),
    po.mfrname)
AS source,

(i.shipping + i.surcharge + 
    (SELECT SUM(additionalshipping * quantity) AS additionalshipping 
        FROM cs_products.tblorderitems 
        WHERE invoiceid=i.invoiceid)) 
AS shipping,

CAST(IF(o.paymentmethod=2, CONCAT('Check: ', i.checknumber),o.paymentmethod) AS CHAR) AS invoicepaidvia,

COALESCE(
    (SELECT (SUM(cost * quantity) * IF(so.mfrdiscount > 0, 1 - so.mfrdiscount, 1)) AS cost 
        FROM cs_products.tblorderitems oi 
        JOIN cs_products.tblallocations a ON oi.orderitemid=a.orderitemid 
        JOIN cs_products.tblstockingorders so ON a.stockingorderid=so.stockingorderid
        WHERE a.stockingorderid=oistockingorderid),
    (SELECT (SUM(cost * quantity) * IF(po.mfrdiscount > 0, 1 - po.mfrdiscount, 1)) AS cost 
        FROM cs_products.tblorderitems 
        WHERE purchaseorderid=po.purchaseorderid)) 
    AS grosscost,

(SELECT SUM(price * quantity)
    FROM cs_products.tblorderitems 
    WHERE invoiceid=i.invoiceid) 
AS grossprice

FROM cs_products.tblorders o 
    JOIN cs_products.tblinvoices i ON o.orderid=i.orderid
    #ordertype of 0 means the order came from the website
    LEFT JOIN cs_products.tblpurchaseorders po ON o.orderid=po.orderid AND IF(o.ordertype<>0, subinvoicenumber=subponumber, subinvoicenumber=0 AND subponumber>=0)
    LEFT JOIN cs_products.tblallocations a ON a.orderid=o.orderid
```

This gets me 95% of the way there. As you can see, for `OrderId` 1287, it shows two records with `stockingorderid`s and none with a `purchaseorderid` even though a purchase order has been attributed to 1287. What I'm expecting to see for the missing row is something like:

```
1287|276|0|NULL|194|0||0|0|'Quality Fabricators'|357.53|0|781.43|11917.70
```

Again, don't worry about the calculated columns, I just want the record to appear. I feel like I'm missing the smallest thing, but I don't know what it is.

Thank you!

**UPDATE** the reason why calculated columns aren't working is because old order item data was used. I'll update it when I get the chance.

Comment: Use IFNULL((Select blah blah), (select blah blah)) the second one is default if not found from first 2nd will run i might not be able to understand but i guess this is what you are looking for

Comment: @Amadan thanks for showing me SQLFiddle. I use JSFiddle and ReFiddle a lot, but I had no idea SQLFiddle existed! I'm creating a SQLFiddle right now and will update my post with it. Thanks!

Comment: @Lieven could you please put your solution in an answer?

Comment: @Jason - I would if it was the right answer. It seems it isn't, sorry <g>

Comment: The sqlfiddle sample data in `tblorderitems` is for an order which is unrelated to the rest of the sample data...

Comment: @eggyal - i included three orders for demo purposes: 1287 is 2 POs and an SO on one invoice, 1288 is 2 POs on one invoice, and 1289 is 2 POs on 2 invoices. there are other scenarios as well, but for simplification, i only included three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest that you use `NULL` (rather than `0`) to represent the `stockingorderid` and `purchaseorderid` of PO and SO records respectively:

```
ALTER TABLE tblorderitems MODIFY purchaseorderid int(10) unsigned NULL;
UPDATE tblorderitems SET purchaseorderid = NULL WHERE purchaseorderid = 0;
```

You can then join your query with a `UNION` subquery that provides a set of all (*order*, *stockingorder*) and (*order*, *purchaseorder*) pairs:

```
  SELECT orderid, stockingorderid, NULL AS purchaseorderid FROM tblallocations
UNION ALL
  SELECT orderid, NULL AS stockingorderid, purchaseorderid FROM tblpurchaseorders
```

I think your query can then be simplified to:

```
SELECT   orderid, invoiceid, subinvoicenumber, purchaseorderid, subponumber,
         tblpurchaseorders.paidvia, dropshipfee, tblinvoices.taxstate,
         invoicedate, datepaid, stockingorderid,

         COALESCE(tblstockingorders.mfrname, tblpurchaseorders.mfrname) AS source,

         shipping + surcharge + SUM(quantity * additionalshipping) AS shipping,

         CASE paymentmethod
           WHEN 2 THEN CONCAT('Check: ', checknumber)
           ELSE CAST(paymentmethod AS CHAR)
         END AS InvoicePaidVia,

         (1-COALESCE(tblstockingorders.mfrdiscount, tblpurchaseorders.mfrdiscount))
           * SUM(quantity * cost) AS grosscost,

         SUM(quantity * price) AS grossprice

FROM     tblorders
  JOIN   tblinvoices          USING (orderid)
  JOIN (
          SELECT orderid, orderitemid, stockingorderid, NULL AS purchaseorderid
          FROM   tblallocations
        UNION ALL
          SELECT orderid, NULL, NULL, purchaseorderid
          FROM   tblpurchaseorders
       ) AS t                 USING (orderid)
  LEFT JOIN tblpurchaseorders USING (orderid,purchaseorderid)
  LEFT JOIN tblstockingorders USING (stockingorderid)
  LEFT JOIN tblorderitems     USING (orderid,orderitemid,invoiceid,purchaseorderid)
WHERE    ordertype = 0 OR subinvoicenumber = subponumber
GROUP BY orderid, invoiceid, subinvoicenumber, purchaseorderid, subponumber,
         tblpurchaseorders.paidvia, dropshipfee, tblinvoices.taxstate, datepaid,
         invoicedate, stockingorderid, shipping, surcharge, paymentmethod,
         tblstockingorders.mfrname, tblpurchaseorders.mfrname, checknumber,
         tblstockingorders.mfrdiscount, tblpurchaseorders.mfrdiscount
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f25a6/77), with references to the `invoicedate` column removed (because it's not present in your sample schema).

Comment: !!! this is super close. the only thing wrong with the result set is there are 4 entries for 1289 where there should only be 2. when multiple invoices exist on an order, their subnumbers must match the corresponding PO subnumber. however, this definitely gets me going in the correct direction (the `USING` keyword is awesome, didn't know about that!)

Comment: on a side note, thank you for rewriting my query. i'm relatively self-taught in the area of SQL and i am learning a LOT just from looking through your query!

Comment: @Jason: See my revised answer.  And re your side note, it's a pleasure :) For the most part, we all started out teaching ourselves at some point, so it's great to be able to help others too (plus I just like the challenge).  The MySQL manual is very helpful (and fairly accessible) if you have the time to sit down and browse it!

Comment: AMAZING. thank you so much. you are a lifesaver, and you have augmented my SQL-fu by an incredible amount. when i get home after work today, i will implement this and most likely accept this answer

Comment: one last thing, do i have to change `purchaseorderid` to NULL?

Comment: @Jason: In the manner shown above? Yes.. or else you'll break the join with `tblorderitems` for stocking orders.  There are other ways around it, but I think what I've shown would be the most elegant/standard/recommended approach.

Comment: what is the reason for using that massive `GROUP BY` statement?

Comment: also, i had to modify your `WHERE` statement to include `OR stockingorderid > 0`

Comment: @Jason: Bearing in mind our new use of `NULL`, you ought to use `OR stockingorderid IS NOT NULL` instead.  The `GROUP BY` clause ensures that each result rolls up all records from `tblorderitems` so that the `SUM` functions do what is intended; if performance is poor, one could instead perform the grouping over only `orderid, purchaseorderid, stockingorderid` in a subquery on `t` and `tblorderitems`.  See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f25a6/90).